# Sending email with Process.Start opens new Message window Twice

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2010, process.start

Why does launching the mail application with `Process.Start` opens two identical New Message windows in Outlook?

This happens only if Outlook is closed, if Outlook is open when the `Process.Start` is called, it works fine.

This is the code we use:

```
Process.Start("mailto:" + NotificationEmailAddress + "?subject=" +
     prefix.ToString() + " | " + subject + " | " + suffix.ToString() + "&body=" + body);
```

I know there are other ways to send an email, and we have them in place already, this is just a fallback option in case of issues with the other options.

I don't understand what we are doing wrong, why is it opening the `New Message` twice? **We are not** calling the `Process.Start` twice.

Comment: Using your code, VIsual Studio 2013 from a console app, with Outlook 2013 both open and closed, I get one new message window.

Comment: @ElliotRodriguez - Thanks for testing! I am using Visual Studio 2013, we are calling the `Process.Start` from a WPF application, both from inside VS and just running the *.exe the issue happens. But, we are using Outlook 2010. Sorry that I didn't point that out before.

Comment: can you attach it to a debugger @Dzyann and set a breakpoint there?

Comment: @ElliotRodriguez - I have, that is why I know is being called only once.

Comment: Not sure then, as I am unable to repro without 2010 installed.

Comment: @ElliotRodriguez - That's ok, thanks for trying!